# Is Adblock filtering my website?

Tags: browser, assets, ads, adblock

How can I bypass it ? It has 'ad' on its hostname, I think this is the reason.

> http://testinad.info

Every resources are blocked. It is completely unviewable by everyone running adblock. Is there anything to do in my code ? Or where to get it deblacklisted ?

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/css/style.css Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/img/logo.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/img/webicon-facebook.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/img/webicon-googleplus.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/img/webicon-twitter.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
http://testinad.info/assets/img/logo.svg Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Because of the following filter

/inad.
Found in: EasyList
```

It's a filter in EasyList.

Comment: This is horrible, how could they do that. My whole website is blocked. Any place to ask them for removal ?